# How to Check and Repair MySQL database Using Mysqlcheck

Tags: mysql

I need repair Mysql database using `Mysqlcheck` command

this is the [guide](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/12/mysqlcheck/)

run `MySQL 5.5 Command Line Client` as Administrator

insert `password`

and run

`mysqlcheck -r mydb`

the return

[image]

I don't understand if working or not ...

Please, can you help me?

Comment: `mysqlcheck` is a command line application, not a query you enter in the MySQL client. Start `mysqlcheck -r` like any other program from the cmd instead.

Comment: in your guide is nithing mentioned that you use the command in mysql client, , as you see in the guide you have to enter the credentiels with the command

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, if the command is not found, and you get this error:

```bash
C:\Users\JayRizzo> mysqlcheck -u root --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases
# 'mysqlcheck' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
# operable program or batch file.
```

Try using the base directory to get the command to run:
Note: Make sure the version is correct. (8.0/8.2/8.3) etc.

```bash
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.3\bin\mysqlcheck.exe" -u root --auto-repair --optimize --all-databases -p
```

After running this command you will be prompted to enter the root password.
Enter the password, upon success you will see it start the process.

This was on Windows 11 Command Prompt (CMD):